# What is the space distribution for disabled system apps?

Tags: root-access, 6.0-marshmallow, systemless-root

My phone is rooted with Magisk. I have a root browser app, allowing me to "sneak peek" into the root directories.

I found, for example, that for the Google Drive app, the APK in `/system/app` is 23MB, but application manager shows the app size as 30MB (excluding 750KB of data). Where is the rest 7MB gone? If I debloat the Drive app, I know I will not be able to use the 23MB as that is in the `system` partition, but will I recover this 7MB?

Comment: Check these folders  `/data/data/com.google.android.apps.docs` and `Android/data/com.google.android.apps.docs` (internal storage or SD card).You will get the 7Mb back. Force stop the app, clear data and cache and then debloat.

Comment: @WrichikBasu [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526) recent answer of mine addresses your question in detail.

Comment: if your phone is rooted install Link2SD it is great in showing size and folder names i use the free version for managing my apps (search/sort/share/clear/freeze) you don't even need the second ext4 partition or linking functionality

Comment: Is the Google Drive app active or disabled? If it is active most likely an update is installed and the app on `system/app` is not used at all as the update installs like a regular app in `/data/app`.

Comment: @Robert it is disabled.

Comment: @alecxs will look into that.

Comment: @Irfan Latif that is a very good answer.