# missing 3gb of internal storage on samsung galaxy grand 2

Tags: storage

I have a samsung galaxy grand 2 which uses android version 4.4.2.
My phone says that i am running out of space and it keeps notifying me about it which is quite disturbing. In settings > storage tab, it says in somewhere there are 2.37 gb of misc file but i cannot find them.
[image]

I have nearly tried every cleaning apps in google play and i am sure that my problem is not just simple as removing junk files or cleaning caches. After that , i used DiskUsage app to analyze and things get more interesting. It says there is only 5.17 gb internal storage in my phone, including system data.

[image]

There are no more photo to delete or no more app to clear. I just wonder where is my nearly 3gb of internal storage or what is this 2.37 gb of misc file. How can i regain that 3gb ?
Can the reason of all this thing some sort of physical damage on my phone that i could never fix instead of software problems ?

Comment: See my answer to [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216087/how-disk-space-is-used-on-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

Files like downloads are included in misc. Try to click on misc the to view them. The misc items can also be seen from any file explorer. In the second image attached, the total storage is more than 5.17 gib. If you add the values visible, the total is 5.78 gib. From what I have seen, there is no missing storage.