# I have an old Xcover 3 and want to access all files as there are 3 GB I cannot access

Tags: internal-storage

Is there a way I can access all or nearly all files including the operating system files?

I would like to see what is eating up space in it. I kept deleting files and without downloading anything or taking photos and more and more space was taken up until the phone was full again.

I ended up installing an SD card and removing a lot of apps I don't use much.
It only has 8GB internal memory, 4.53 GB of space shows up when connected to a PC which makes sense with the system memory being 3.13GB.

I have now deleted and removed as much as I can and it shows 1.38 GB free. When I first got it there was much more free space than that.

It is running 6.0.1 and shows:

system memory 3.44GB

used space 3.13GB

available space 1.38 GB

which adds up to 7.95 GB.

I would like to know what is in the 3.13 GB used space as all the files and folders I can see with a PC is 24 MB.

dialing *#9900# (Delete dumpstate/logcat) has no effect

Comment: See my answer to [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216087)

Comment: Thanks, I loaded a terminal emulator and found Knox is using 3.2GB. On the app info it just shows a few MB. It looks like I will have to root it to see what is in there.

Comment: Without root you can't be 100% sure where space is being used. But in most cases it's possible to get a close estimate.

Comment: I have seen that rooting it may cause a problem with Knox. As this is a work phone I don't want to mess too much with it as I am sending it back soon as I have a new one. What could Knox be storing that woud take up over 3 GB?

Comment: If it is a work phone the admins of your company may use the work profile feature. In that case all apps that run inside the Knox protected area may be included in that 3.2 GB storage size calculation. Therefore check all your work apps for their data usage. Especially mail and browser app usually cache a lot of data. In the end it is like Irfan said, if you don't find the causing app(s) by chance you will never know it without root - hence you have to live with it. And complain at your company buying 8GB phones - 16GB+ is the minimum today for a usable phone.

Comment: The phone was supposed to be temporary, I have had it 3 years. We have had a change of manager and now have Samsung A50's

Comment: There was talk that the old manager was monitoring our calls and possibly controlling the microphone and maybe the camera. 
There were a few people who said he knew things they had not told anyone else at work or just one person by phone. He put live (by 4G) cameras in our vehicles and trackers that analyze our driving. Glad he's gone. 
I was wondering if there was any data hidden in the phone that would prove this.