# File Sizes (including hidden files) don't sum up to total data usage

Tags: internal-storage, hidden

I recently noticed that my Galaxy S9 was running low on space. While using the 'My Files' app that comes with the phone to do some spring cleaning, I noticed that my Internal Storage shows a usage of about 47GB.
However, something doesn't add up. I open that folder, turn on display of hidden files, and select EVERYTHING that is listed. The result is only 13.72GB!?!?!?!?!!! This is WAY WAY off. I have a huge amount of space getting used (over 30GB) and no idea what is actually using it, nor how to clear it out.

I have tried using cache cleaners, like Norton Clean, but those only found about 1GB of residual files, etc. I have also tried restarting the phone, but this doesn't help either... Other than a factor default reset, I can't think of anything else to try. Can anyone help me figure out what is going on?

Comment: See my answer to [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216087/how-disk-space-is-used-on-android-device)

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you needed to gain root access for a lot of that... is there anyway to find / clean out the junk without rooting my phone? I ask because if I root my phone I may not be able to access internet at work which has a policy of denying access to rooted phones.

Comment: Clean `/sdcard` AMAP. Clear app caches or complete data. Uninstall unnecessary apps. Or perform a complete factory reset.