# How do I empty trash bin on phone?

Tags: storage, ram, delete

Please help. When photos and videos ef is are deleted,  where do they go? I'd like to delete everything in my " trash", as my storage is always full.
Thank you.

Comment: See my answer to [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526). May help you understand how space is used and why it gets full.

Answer (score 1):

Android does not have the concept of trash bin or recycle (unlike windows).

When you delete a file, it is not actually deleted but the space it occupied is marked as free and therefore can be used to store data (that's why file recovery is possible using apps).

So, your storage being always full is not because of files in trash. It can be for a bunch of other reasons like remnants of uninstalled apps, system logs, duplicates etc. I would suggest you use this app [SD Maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm) to clean your phone. Pro version allows you to schedule cleaning.

I have no affiliation with the app and recommend it strongly

Comment: Some file explorers and galleries etc. provide trash bin as their internal feature. So the files - if deleted using those apps - are moved to some hidden directory on external or app's internal storage. Just to mention :)

Comment: @IrfanLatif Yes. I thought of mentioning ES and MX that do this but left it out as the focus here is on cleaning :)

Comment: Moreover, even the free version of SD Maid allows to index the installed apps and list them according to their size, so that one can then wipe their data via Android itself.