# How to view which files are on internal memory, and which are on SD Card (formatted as Internal Storage)?

Tags: internal-storage, storage, internal-sd

On Android 9 (Pie) how to visualize **SD Card** (formatted as Internal) **vs Internal Storage**? I need them differentiated, as I'm chronically out of space and can't download apps, but have 200+ GB on my SD card.

The OS does not seem to differentiate between the two physical storage devices, as far as I can tell. Is it possible without rooting?

Bonus points if it's doable in a nice visual structure like SpaceMonger / WinDirStat / Baobab. Here's an example of the SpaceMonger User Interface where you can immediately identify the problem areas
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216087/how-disk-space-is-used-on-android-device)

Comment: Seems to be an answer that requires Rooting the device. Is there another way?

Comment: i don't know of any, search on [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=disk+usage) or [F-Droid](https://search.f-droid.org/?q=disk+usage) or [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=disk+usage&c=apps)