# Android system memory filled up Samsung Galaxy s8

Tags: samsung, insufficient-memory, system, ram, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I have a Samsung Galaxy S8 since 2 years. After time my free memory got less and less but my Samsung File manager only said that Others had (As of today) 47,26GB and in the Internet i did not found any description what "Others" is.
After a bit digging in how to read out the Phone memory a found a programm in die Playstore ([Diskusage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=de)) which exactly displays what uses how much memory. 
There the Programme showed a that a few Gigabites get used by the system memory (Around 20GB)

Now probobly 3 Month Later my free memory got even worse so I checked the Programm every Day and the systemm memory growes around 600megabites per Day. Now its around 21,2GB

My Momes phone with the same software variant uses just 600mb in total for system memory.

Any ideas to fix with out resetting my phone.

Comment: What does 1) Settings-> Apps; Tap on Three dots/menu, Sort By, Size tell you? 2) Are the apps with the biggest storage usage the ones you use regularly?

Comment: No only the first two with 1.30 and 1.11 GB with regular use. The rest has normal storage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216087/how-disk-space-is-used-on-android-device)