# Android System storage usage blew from 7GB to 40GB overnight,Magisk problems?

Tags: insufficient-memory, magisk

I have LineageOS 17.1 with Magisk on my phone and this night system storage usage blew from 7GB to 40 GB

```
dreamlte:/ # df -h
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                           1.6G  492K  1.6G   1% /dev
tmpfs                           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /mnt
tmpfs                           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /apex
/dev/block/sda3                  16M  2.5M   13M  17% /efs
tmpfs                           1.6G  4.9M  1.6G   1% /sbin
/sbin/.magisk/block/system_root 4.1G  2.0G  2.1G  49% /sbin/.magisk/mirror/system_root
/dev/block/sda18                484M  704K  484M   1% /cache
/dev/block/loop2                 95M   95M   36K 100% /apex/com.android.runtime@1
/dev/block/loop3                5.5M  5.5M   28K 100% /apex/com.android.media@290000000
/dev/block/loop4                232K   36K  196K  16% /apex/com.android.apex.cts.shim@1
/dev/block/loop5                 24M   24M   28K 100% /apex/com.android.media.swcodec@290000000
/dev/block/loop6                840K  812K   28K  97% /apex/com.android.tzdata@290000000
/dev/block/loop7                1.6M  1.6M   28K  99% /apex/com.android.resolv@290000000
/dev/block/loop8                5.0M  5.0M   28K 100% /apex/com.android.conscrypt@299900000
/sbin/.magisk/block/data         54G   49G  4.1G  93% /sbin/.magisk/mirror/data
tmpfs                           1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /system/etc/permissions
tmpfs                           1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /system/priv-app
tmpfs                           1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /system/lib
tmpfs                           1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /system/lib64
tmpfs                           1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /system/framework
/data/media                      54G   49G  4.1G  93% /mnt/runtime/default/emulated
/dev/block/vold/public:179,1     29G  7.6G   22G  27% /mnt/media_rw/B351-0D99
/mnt/media_rw/B351-0D99          29G  7.6G   22G  27% /mnt/runtime/default/B351-0D99
```

Comment: As you have root you can exactly track what files occupy the storage space. Once you know the file(s) it is usually not a big problem to understand what app/service has created the files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216087/how-disk-space-is-used-on-android-device)