# Is there a "recycle bin" option in EMUI 9.1.0?

Tags: huawei, delete, emui

I have deleted 47G worth of photos and no space has freed up. I have a Huawei Honor 9 (STF-AL10) EMUI 9.1.0 phone that I bought in China. What do I need to do in order to claim back that space that is still for someone reason occupied by my deleted photos?

Thank you.

Comment: Which app did you use to delete photos? Unlike other OS's trash/recycle bin would be separate for each app. If it is a Gallery app, look for something  called trash or deleted. Same goes for default file manager. Other option is to use an app called Diskusage. It would scan your internal storage and show a hierarchal view of what is taking most space.

Comment: May help: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526

Comment: I used the HiSuite on my PC.