# Android du and df very different: File System Corrupted?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, file-system

On an Android Nougat (7.1.1) set top box, `du` and `df` of my `/data` partition are very different:

```
$ adb shell du -sh /data
1.0G    /data
$ adb shell df -H /data
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/block/sda9  10G   10G  469M  96% /data
```

I don’t think that anything else is mounted under `/data`:

```
$ adb shell mount | grep "\/data"
/dev/block/sda9 on /data type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,discard,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered)
$ adb shell mount | grep "sda9"
/dev/block/sda9 on /data type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,discard,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered)
```

`lsof` indicates to me that there are dozens of processes holding hundreds of small deleted files of the sort

```
init          1       root    3w      CHR               1,11       0t0      14517 /dev/__kmsg__ (deleted)
ueventd     391       root    3w      CHR               1,11       0t0      14593 /dev/__kmsg__ (deleted)
  . . .
main        756       root  mem   unknown                                         /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted)
main        756       root  mem   unknown                                         /dev/ashmem/dalvik-large object space allocation (deleted)
  . . .
omm.times  3934     system  mem   unknown                                         /dev/ashmem/dalvik-mark sweep sweep array free buffer (deleted)
omm.times  3934     system  mem   unknown                                         /dev/ashmem/dalvik-mark sweep sweep array free buffer (deleted)
```

Using `busybox`, results are different (`df` shows much less usage), but there is still a large discrepancy between `du` and `df`:

```
$ adb shell busybox du -sh /data
389.4M  /data
$ adb shell busybox df -h /data
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata
                          9.7G      8.6G      1.1G  89% /data
```

And using `toybox`, the results are similar to `busybox`:

```
$ adb shell toybox du -sh /data
389M    /data
$ adb shell toybox df -h /data
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/block/sda9  10G  8.6G  1.1G  89% /data
```

It think that it's important to note that ***these numbers remain similar after a reboot***.

Also, I wish to note that I cannot OTA update this device's Android due to running out of disk space, even though the OTA image is only about 1GB in size. This fact leads me to believe that the results of `df` are accurate in terms of actual available disk space.

All adb commands are run as root i.e., I did `adb root` before executing them. But at risk of making this question be too verbose, here's everything run at the adb prompt:

```
$ adb shell
Z:/ # whoami
root
Z:/ # du -sh /data
389M    /data
Z:/ # df -h /data
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/block/sda9  10G  8.6G  1.1G  89% /data
10.197.12.14:/ # busybox du -sh /data
389.4M  /data
Z:/ # busybox df -h /data
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata
                          9.7G      8.6G      1.1G  89% /data
Z:/ # toybox du -sh /data
389M    /data
Z:/ # toybox df -h /data
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/block/sda9  10G  8.6G  1.1G  89% /data
Z:/ #
```

A user in comments has asked for the following:

```
Z:/ # while read num; do (( sum += num )); done <<< $(find /data -type f -exec stat -c%b {} +); expr $sum / 2048
393
```

I understand that `du` reports free space by scanning reachable nodes, and that this could therefore mean that my file system is corrupt. However, unfortunately, this is for devices in the field, and I don’t want to have to (and don’t think I can) run `fsck` or `e2fsck`.

What might be causing the huge difference between `du` and `df` on this device, and how might this problem be resolved? I’m happy to provide further logs.

Comment: `df` and `du` mostly differ somewhat (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120312/262728) why) but not that much. There seems to be some problem with your `du` binary. Use a different one. See here what you should expect: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Comment: You've called to both as "normal user". So `df` can report the "free space" (aka "Disk Free") normally – while `du` can only sum up what the user has access to. Nothing broken, works as designed. Try both as root, see the screenshot by @alecxs

Comment: Thanks, @IrfanLatif. I added busybox results to the original question.

Comment: @Izzy Per my original description, I called them as root.

Comment: @zippy your original description shows your commands prefixed with a `$`. Commands called as root carry a `#`. But I indeed missed your comment on `adb root` (also as it's quite uncommon; I never had a ROM allowing me that on any of my devices, not even custom ROMs). But yes, you can run fsck (even in read-only mode if you prefer), it is available on-device.

Comment: https:/i.stack.imgur.com/n0cBI.png https:/i.stack.imgur.com/qwTbp.png

Comment: @alecxs -- I put the results of that command into the description. Our busybox is here: https://links-w.astronics.com/MBSlU8bHA_k/  password "busybox.zip" without the quotes. And what I haven't mentioned yet is that I cannot OTA upgrade this unit due to disk full (!).

Comment: 393M sum of all files (with read access) is congruent with `du`. busybox v1.15.3 works fine too. thought about hard-links but that should produce opposite results, so no idea :(

Comment: check *'du -sh /proc/\*/\*/mnt'* (not sure this is helpful as i have disabled mount namespace separation in SuperSU completely and don't know how to check)

Comment: The reason for a delay in responding is that a customer was visiting this week. @alexcs, I tried the remount, but it doesn't seem to have an effect. I'm also trying to build an fsck for Nougat on aarch64 on toybox (there is none built in) but that's not working. Can anyone point me to an aarch64 fsck?

Comment: /system/bin/e2fsck

Comment: please try to set selinux permissive with setenforce/getenforce. Now lazy umount, kill system_server, re-mount sda9 to another dir and check again

Comment: today got Mecool KII Pro S905D on my hands. realized these tv box are shipped with busybox pre-rooted userdebug builds. selinux is permissive but namespaces are isolated. with no superuser app at all no clue how to set global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /data partition was indeed corrupted.

After running `e2fsck -p /dev/block/sda9`, here was the updated `du` and `df` (again, after doing an `adb root`):

```
$ adb shell du -s /data
1.3G    /data
$ adb shell df -H /data
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/block/sda9  10G  1.5G  8.9G  15% /data
```

After fixing the file system, the device ran properly and updated successfully thereafter.

(Note that I found that I had to run `e2fsck` with the `-p` option; it wouldn't run interactively for some reason.)

A portion of the output of the above `e2fsck` command is

```
data contains a file system with errors, check forced.
data: Deleted inode 163845 has zero dtime.  FIXED.
data: Deleted inode 163847 has zero dtime.  FIXED.
data: Deleted inode 163849 has zero dtime.  FIXED.
   . . . [snip ] . . .
data: Deleted inode 213003 has zero dtime.  FIXED.
data: Deleted inode 262223 has zero dtime.  FIXED.
data: Deleted inode 303108 has zero dtime.  FIXED.
data: 5203/655360 files (2.0% non-contiguous), 186831/2621440 blocks
```

There were a total of 140 lines of the sort `data: Deleted inode...`

FWIW, we are guessing that this problem was possibly caused by the filesystem becoming full with logs, which then caused corruption during the next attempted download of OTA updates: Those downloads failed, but thereafter left the file system in a corrupted state. Subsequent attempts at those downloads seemed to further corrupt the file system.

Thanks very much to @alecxs for your persistence and relevant details. (However, please note that to run `e2fsck`, the partition /dev/block/sda9 had to be UNmounted.)

Answer (score 2):

`df` stands for "Disk Free". That means, it just needs to check with the "global file system information" about free space (accessible for all users). The size of the file system itself is also "globally available". The difference logically is the "used space". Done.

`du` works differently: not on file system level but on file level. It needs to look up each directory and file separately, gather it's size, and sum that up. So it can only take into account what it has access to.

Now you've run both commands as "normal user" – who has no permission to traverse e.g. `/data/data` (where all the apps' data is stored). So it can only sum up a portion of what space is occupied on `/data`. Would you run both commands as root user (as the screenshot in the comment by [alecxs](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/170470/alecxs) shows), numbers would be much closer together – as usually root can access all files. Though as again Alex correctly points out: there is still [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SELinux) which might deny full access – which according to him is a known issue for `mtk-su` on the Amazon FireTV stick, and might be the culprit here, and isolated mount [namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces) could be yet another reason for invisible files.

**TL;DR:** there's neither a file system corruption, nor a broken `du` binary necessarily causing the difference. All might work as designed. If you want to make sure, you can run `fsck` (if you prefer, in read-only mode) to rule out the former – and set up a test case on a different place for the latter.

Comment: per the comment in my description, I already ran du and df as root. Here is confirmation:
$ adb shell

Z:/ # su

Z:/ # whoami

root

Z:/ # du -sh /data

389M    /data

Z:/ # df -H /data

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/block/sda9  10G  9.2G  1.1G  89% /data

Comment: Yes, apologies – I missed that in the last paragraphs (got distracted by those huge images in the comments below – no idea why SE meanhile displays them inline, bad idea IMHO). If you want I can hence remove my answer as "invalid". Or I can leave it as it might help those not being aware of the different approaches.

Comment: I prefer that you delete it because it doesn't directly address the question (and I had found that these procedures need to be done as root elsewhere). Thanks.

Comment: Conflicting wishes. @zippy does my edit change your mind?