# Why no storage error showing with my space empty?

Tags: google-play-store, updates, internal-storage, downloading

Im having more than 12GB free space

[image]

And when i try to install app or update app im getting **no storage** error. I have clear cache also still showing same issue. Any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Do you use an sd-card mounted as internal storage (adopted storage)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216087/how-disk-space-is-used-on-android-device)

Comment: @Robert No i dont use SD cards