# Android incorrect reporting of storage usage

Tags: internal-storage, storage

I have a moto g 7 power running android 10. I am attempting to clear out some storage. In the storage portion of the settings app, it shows 4.6GB of audio, but when I go to delete those files, it states there are none there.

I'm unsure if there are files the phone is somehow unable to detect or if its log of contents is holding an error. Either way, is there a way to clear out this storage usage?

Comment: Are they in the recycle bin?

Comment: See my answer to [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216087/how-disk-space-is-used-on-android-device)