# ES File Explorer - Space not freed after deletion from Recycle Bin

Tags: delete, es-file-explorer, thumbnails

Every few months, my internal storage begins to fill up.

I store everything I can to SD Card, but Android has a limited ability to do so.  I'm running Oreo, unrooted.

The biggest dir by far is /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/.thumbnails/, which can stand around 3.1GB for some reason.  I used ES File Explorer to delete it, then went to the Recycle Bin in the app and emptied it.  The 3GB was not freed-up.

I've restarted my phone several times, looked around for residual files, could not find LOST.dir.  I'm honestly at a loss.  Where did it go?

How can I get the OS to free up this space?
What better way can I use to get rid of this stuff?

Comment: What Android version? How to you check how much free space you have? An alternative way would be to look at the free space of the user partition e.g. in {DiskInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216087/how-disk-space-is-used-on-android-device)

Comment: It might be issue with file system. Unfortunately you can't do much without root access (for example checking discrepancy between df and du). Factory reset is your last option