# How can I find out where all my storage space is gone?

Tags: internal-storage, file-system, storage, internal-sd

I've seen lots of posts here and elsewhere, including YouTube videos, about how to free up space on your android device or find out where it's all gone, including multiple redmi-specific ones, but none of them are helping.

I have a Redmi Node 7 32GB which is not rooted. I'm not a heavy user and none of my apps have a huge amount of data or cache, and I don't have any photos or music on it.

on MIUI settings/about/storage it shows 9GB "System", 7GB "apps and data", 13GB "other" and a few other small categories, and there is about 2GB free. I've tried all the built-in clean features and they don't show anything much available to reclaim.

When I mount the phone onto my PC, I can only see about 3.7GB of files, and this matches up with what I can see in the android file manager under "Internal shared storage". I've tried a couple of other file managers as well and they're all showing the same file system.

I've tried the "diskusage" app - this shows a total drive size of 21 GB (which I'm guessing is maybe everything except "system"?) and 16GB of that is under "System data" - the remainder comprising the same 3.7GB I see in file manager, plus the 2GB free space.

I also tried "disk and storage analyser" (aka "drives"). this similarly shows a total drive size of 21GB but again the analysis of what files are on it again adds up to 3.7GB, and those are the only ones it can delete.

All the instructions I've found online are either (a) deleting cached files or app data or (b) deleting files that can be seen by file manager, but all of this adds up to peanuts compared to the 20GB + of "system" + "other" files. Is there any way I can find or clean them without rooting the phone?

Comment: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully resolved the issue myself, but these could be of help:

- Open Gallery > Albums > (scroll) Recycled bin/Trash > Clear all

**Some of the "Other" file storage are in app based and do not show on the file manager or even the system memory. They often include: Downloaded system update and temp/log files like thumbnail-types.

Comment: Thanks - that didn't help for me but I also concluded that a lot of the "other" is just stuff you can't clear up because you can't see it. In the end I had to factory reset which reduced the "other" down quite a lot. It's creeping up slowly again but should give me at least a year before I have to reset again. I was tempted to root it just so I could investigate but didn't want to bear the risk of bricking the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to revive a 3-year-old Xiaomi Redmi 7A by releasing almost 3 GiB of memory on the card by using this procedure (iterative, but streamlined):

```
Settings > Apps > Manage Apps > (three dots) > 
Show all apps > (sorting control) > Sort by used storage > 
(select apps one-by-one, moving down) > Storage > Clear all data
```