# How to clean up knox filesystem

Tags: internal-storage, android-10, samsung-galaxy-s-9, samsung-knox

My Samsung galaxy S9 is giving me notifications to say I am using over 90% of my internal storage. This confused me as the built in file manager (and a couple others I downloaded) showed closer to 10GB used.

I have downloaded termux and run `df -h` and received the following result.

```
Filesystem                                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/block/dm-0                                4.1G  4.0G  153M  97% /
tmpfs                                          1.7G  1.2M  1.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs                                          1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /mnt
tmpfs                                          1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /mnt/sde
tmpfs                                          1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /apex
/dev/block/dm-1                                622M  617M  4.9M 100% /odm
/dev/block/dm-2                                618M  548M   70M  89% /vendor
/dev/block/platform/11120000.ufs/by-name/CACHE 581M  135M  446M  24% /cache
/dev/block/platform/11120000.ufs/by-name/EFS    16M  2.8M   13M  18% /efs
/dev/block/dm-3                                 53G   48G  4.1G  93% /data
/data/knox/data_de/150                          53G   48G  4.1G  93% /data/user_de/150
/data/knox/data/150                             53G   48G  4.1G  93% /data/user/150
/data/knox/misc_ce/150                          53G   48G  4.1G  93% /data/misc_ce/150
/data/knox/secure_fs/enc_user                   53G   48G  4.1G  93% /data/enc_user
/data/knox/secure_fs/enc_media                  53G   48G  4.1G  93% /data/knox/secure_fs/enc_medi
```

It looks like the Knox folder has reached 53GB (of a total of 64GB storage). Am I safe to delete this? If so what is the best way to delete/shrink it?

**TL;DR** Knox filesystem has reached 53GB, how can I reduce/remove it?

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the listing. Your user data partition `/data` has a size of 53GB (64GB - system partition) with 48GB used. Which program is causing this usage can not be determined from the listing you have provided. And file managers always only see the shared space but never the app-private data. Please read https://android.stackexchange.com/q/216087/2241