# Is it possible to manage Android Storage and Free Space through PC?

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, file-management, realme

So my 64 GB phone (Realme 5 - 4 GB RAM variant) is throwing warnings of storage being full despite having 5-6 GB of free storage.

As you can imagine, file management is kind of tricky on a smartphone.

I was wondering if there is a way to seek out large file and folder sizes on Android storage **by connecting the phone to Windows** and using a utility like **Space Sniffer** ( which finds big files on HDDs/USBs etc)

Space Sniffer did not work on the phone storage, but i was wondering if the good people here could suggest me something relevant to help me out

Edit : I might not have emphasized upon this , but i want to manage Android storage by connecting the phone on my PC, as it is much convenient to select and delete multiple files that way.

Comment: The answer is mostly No. First Android uses the MTP protocol to communicate with Windows, and MTP is handled only Explorer-internal so no drive letter and no access for other programs. Second Android exposes only the shared public folders to a PC which is depending on what you store just the tip of the ice berg. The app-private data can not be mananged this way.

Comment: May help in understanding the situation in-depth: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Comment: @Robert thanks for the comprehensive description. I am not looking to remove app private data, that can be somewhat easily managed using apps. But since Android does not share folder sizes with Windows, that's what really hampers finding big chunks of files. I understand it can be done using an app like [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage) which is easily available on Google Play Store, but i was hoping to achieve something similar on Windows but for Android devices.

Comment: None of the file-systems Windows can use shares the accumulated size of a folder. Windows Explorer always calculates it by summing up all contained files and folders. Most likely because MTP protocol is so painfully slow Windows Explorer does not try to do the same on MTP devices. MTP is designed just for simple file exchange, nothing more. For a more detailed access I recommend enable develop options and ADB. On adb shell you can use standard Linux command-line programs to search for large files.