# How to free the space called 'Other'

Tags: internal-storage

How can I eliminate this 9.21 GB of space called "Altro" (Other);
Is there the possibility to know what kind of things are there in this 9 GB, I tried some apps but none gives me some useful info.
I am on android 12, xiaomi mi 9t.

[image]

Comment: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Comment: Unfortunately on an unrooted phone it is impossible to see what files and folders Android categorizes as "Other". You can only check the shared folder `/sdcard` (e.g. from a connected PC or a file-manager app) and the installed apps (clear cache/data of unused apps or uninstall/disable them).

Answer (score 0):

You can't (possibly) 'eliminate' the contents without SU access. However MixPlorer or ES file Explorer might help you read much of / level contents.