# Android lost disk space

Tags: internal-storage, storage

in my Huawei P10 Pro 64Gb the free space is running low, so I checked at the memory page to have a look where all the space is allocated.

So, in the following screenshot, some things are to me not so clear.. The sum of the space for each single item type (images, video..) is 46Gb, but the bar on the top of the view says that the total is 57,34Gb!! So.. where ~11Gb of data are gone lost? Are they OS images, updates, patches downloaded in the past time and never cleaned by the system, once installed?

Second: 26,8Gb Apps is a huge disk space. I've about 150 different Apps installed on my phone, so each App should have a weight of about ~190Mb.. and this is impossible! Ok Facebook, Whatsapp, Instagram with all the data space, but there are many little apps that are less than 10Mb.. Really impossibile to have 26,8Gb used only by Apps!

What seems to me is that in this 4 years of smartphone life, the occupied space growed up constantly, like if somewhat in the backgroud eated space without cleaning the "garbage". Ok for the new pictures and video, but all the rest remained the same, in terms of installed Apps.

Now, what can I do to understand where this space is left, and how to manually delete garbage and recover some free space back?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: We get this question about once per month. This dialog only shows you a subset of storage that us used, the shown sizes do not sum-up for most devices. Calculations are therefore useless, no matter as a user you don't have access to the most of the storage data.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/216087/44325)

Comment: side note from linked duplicate: 64 GB = 59.6 GiB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216087/how-disk-space-is-used-on-android-device)