# How to investigate what is hogging disk space

Tags: file-system, file-management

Even after cleaning all picture and documents, and most applications, on my tablet using standard Android tools, the internal storage is still reported as full.

I now experience similar problems on my much newer Samsung phone.
I suspect some applications may leave some data behind even after uninstallation.

On PC I would simply use trusty low level file manager, like Total Commander and let it compute actual (content) size of all directories recursively and focused on biggest culprits.

But on Android I struggle to find file manager application to do something similar.

I was also warned that no file management app would be limited in wider directory access to do such search.

So, how to investigate what is hogging my disk space?

Comment: Question was originally asked here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/244974/which-file-manager-supports-sorting-directories-by-their-actual-size
and there are already helpful comments but was requested to reformulate

Comment: Question for software recommendation was moved here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/81945/which-android-file-manager-supports-sorting-directories-by-their-actual-size

Comment: Does this help: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/96277)