# Tens of Giggs can't be used

Tags: insufficient-memory, samsung-galaxy-note-9

My storage filled up and I investigated what takes so much space. I found that in Astro app, when I select all my apps it goes to about 80 of 128. In "My files" I set the settings to show hidden files and when I select everything it's also somewhere about 80. What happened to the 50 Giggs? How can I free them up?
Galaxy note 9, 3 years old.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! You might wish to take a look at [What can I do to manage my phone's internal storage?](/q/2065/16575), our [insufficient-memory tag wiki](/tags/insufficient-memory/info) and the tag's [most frequent questions](/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory?tab=Frequent). Please check some of the solutions you find there, then **[edit]** and update your question with what you've tried or, if you managed to solve your issue, be welcome to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer). Best luck!

Comment: backup your pictures from *'adb pull -a /sdcard'* and do factory reset

Comment: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)