# How to show all folder sizes of Android phone in Windows file explorer?

Tags: internal-storage, windows, file-management, cleanup

When I run space analysis it shows about 50GB of others, and I don't what is that exactly, so I wanted to manage the space on file explorer on windows 11, but the thing is it doesn't show the folder & file sizes.
So how can I manage internal storage of the android phone on windows?
Phone: Samsung Galaxy A8 (2018) SM-530F
Android Version: 9.0

Comment: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Comment: Cross-posted from Super User: https://superuser.com/q/1728533/356789