# There's only 5.5 gb of stuff on my GalaxyTab A, why is my storage almost full?

Tags: storage, samsung-galaxy-tab

[image]

I've deleted as much as I can. I only have a handful of apps and two pictures.

Comment: In this list the OS and other system-internal partitions are missing. Usually you have two OS partitions as well as some vendor and other internal partitions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216087/how-disk-space-is-used-on-android-device)