# System internal storage expected sizes on android smartphones

Tags: internal-storage, system

The storage numbers that appears in Android devices are hard to understand.

I have look at Android devices with internal storage of 64GB and with System occupying 24GB and Android devices with internal storage of 32GB whose System takes only 9GB.

What is the reason for this variability? When you install new App's it takes Application space and System space?

Is there some specification on how much System could take on an Android device by OS? LIke Android 11 (from 5GB - 10GB), Android 12 (10GB to 15GB)  etc...?
Or the Android OS familiy has nothing to do with System space and all it depends on the manufacturer, like Samsung could decide to take 40GB of space under System if he wish?

Regarding the space taken by System, how we expect the space would remain constant or we must expect it would increase linearly over time? At which rate?

Sorry if the questions have no sense. Feel free to

Comment: See my answer to [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216087/how-disk-space-is-used-on-android-device)

Comment: System space is fixed, you have one main partition and may be several smaller partitions that usually don't change during the phone's life-time. This is the system space you can only read but not write apps or data to. Some vendors pack a lot of bloatware and third party apps into their system image. Additionally on certain devices the system partition exist twice for seamless update installation in background (A/B partition scheme).